# Request Rate Limiting using Redis using spring cloud gateway

Tags: java, redis, spring-cloud-gateway

Can Some one give me a sample example of how to implement Request rate limiting using redis in spring cloud gateway .

I was trying to implement it but doesn’t, A sample Implementation would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Create a rateLimter configration

```java
// Import all required packages

@Configuration
public class RedisRateLimiterConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ReactiveRedisOperations<String, String> redisOperations;

    @Bean
    public RedisRateLimiter redisRateLimiter() {
        return new RedisRateLimiter(redisOperations);
    }
}
```

the in you gatewayconfig

create a bean

```java
    @Bean
    public RedisRateLimiter redisRateLimiter(RedisRateLimiterConfig redisRateLimiterConfig) {
        return redisRateLimiterConfig.redisRateLimiter();
    }
```

then in your routeLocator Bean add

`.setRateLimiter(redisRateLimiter)`

for more info please check this [Rate Limiting With Client IP in Spring Cloud Gateway](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-rate-limit-by-client-ip)